Terraform: Reference YAML list
I'm creating Grafana Alerts using Terraform and I've created a YAML config which I'm trying to reference in Terraform modules but I'm facing some issues while I'm referencing nested lists.
My YAML config "rules.yaml":
dashboard_uid: "my-dashboard"
env:
  staging:
    folder_uid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    datasource_uid: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    load_balancer: "my-loadbalancer"

datasource_config:
  cloudwatch_config: &cloudwatch_config
      datasource:
        type: cloudwatch
        uid: "${datasource_uid}"
      intervalMs: 50
      logGroups: []
      matchExact: true
      maxDataPoints: 1500
      metricEditorMode: 0
      metricQueryType: 0
      period: ""
      queryMode: Metrics
      region: default
      sqlExpression: ""

common_rule_config: &common_rule_config
    no_data_state: "KeepLast"
    exec_err_state: "KeepLast"
    interval_seconds: 60
    labels: {}
    is_paused: true
    for: "1m"

common_data_config: &common_data_config
    relative_time_range:
      from: 60
      to: 0

rules:
  - name: "My Alert"
    condition: "B"
    <<: *common_rule_config
    annotations:
      __alertId__: "1"
      __dashboardUid__: "${dashboard_uid}"
      __panelId__: "3"
      message: "${load_balancer}: HTTP Code Counts alert"
    data_blocks:
      - ref_id: "A"
        <<: *common_data_config
        datasource_uid: "${datasource_uid}"
        model:
          <<: *cloudwatch_config
          alias: "2XX"
          dimensions:
            LoadBalancer: "${load_balancer}"
          label: "2XX"
          metricName: "HTTPCode_Target_2XX_Count"
          namespace: "AWS/ApplicationELB"
          refId: "A"
          statistic: "Sum"
      - ref_id: "D"
        <<: *common_data_config
        datasource_uid: "${datasource_uid}"
        model:
          datasource_config: *cloudwatch_config
          alias: "5XX"
          dimensions:
            LoadBalancer: "${load_balancer}"
          label: "5XX"
          metricName: "HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count"
          namespace: "AWS/ApplicationELB"
          refId: "D"
          statistic: "Sum"
      - ref_id: "B"
        <<: *common_data_config
        datasource_uid: "__expr__"
        model:
          conditions:
            - evaluator:
                params: [20]
                type: "lt"
              operator:
                type: "or"
              query:
                params: ["A"]
              reducer:
                params: []
                type: "avg"
            - evaluator:
                params: [0]
                type: "gt"
              operator:
                type: "or"
              query:
                params: ["D"]
              reducer:
                params: []
                type: "avg"
          intervalMs: 1000
          maxDataPoints: 43200
          refId: "B"
          type: "classic_conditions"

My Terraform module:
locals {
  alert_rules = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/rules.yaml"))

}

resource "grafana_rule_group" "rule_group_0000" {
  name             = "My Alerts"
  folder_uid       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  interval_seconds = 60

    dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = local.alert_rules["rules"]
    content {
      name      = rule.value["name"]
      condition = rule.value["condition"]

      dynamic "data" {
        for_each = rule.value["data_blocks"]
        content {
          ref_id = data.value["ref_id"]
          relative_time_range {
            from = 60
            to   = 0
          }
          datasource_uid = ""
          model = jsonencode({
            model = data.value["model"]
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Now structure of models are different in data blocks, I want to know how can I reference it and is it possible to reference the entire list directly without needing to set individual key-values . Also, I'm using anchors and aliases in YAML config; will this work with it or do I need to remove them.
I tried using dynamic "model" within dynamic "data" but it didn't allow me to do so and threw an error.

I see an issue here: the yamldecode function can't resolve YAML anchors and aliases, and you need to rewrite your rules.yaml or use a tool like pyyaml to preprocess the file.
Also, I think you can simplify a little bit your terraform:
for model for me work construction like:
model = jsonencode(data.value["model"])

and for relative_time_range you can get the data from your yaml:
relative_time_range {
  from = data.value["relative_time_range"]["from"]
  to   = data.value["relative_time_range"]["to"]
}

